# Is there a built in function in PHP to compare a variable with many variables in an array?

Tags: php

```
$numbers = array('1','2','3','4');
$number = '1';
```

Is there any way to compare all numbers with a number to see if some of the values is equal to $number?

Comment: `in_array(1,  array('1','2','3','4'))`, or explain more clearly what you need.

Comment: Next time try Googling. Scanning [this list](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) would've probably revealed your answer

Comment: Michael is Right. Array-search will work as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is:

```
if(in_array(1, array('1','2','3','4')))
{
     echo 'It in here';
}else{ echo 'nope its not';}
```